# Powershell rename all files in all subfolders based on folder name

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to rename all files in all subfolders to prefix it with the folder name
So that all files in all subdirectories under d:\ are renamed to be  .

eg

| Existing folder | Existing Filename | New Filename |
| --- | --- | --- |
| d:\2023_09_28 Sydney | my doc.doc | d:\2023_09_28 Sydney\2023_09_28 Sydney my doc.doc |
| d:\2023_09_28 Sydney | my file.doc | d:\2023_09_28 Sydney\2023_09_28 Sydney my file.doc |
| d:\2023_09_29 Brisbane | my doc.doc | d:\2023_09_29 Brisbane\2023_09_29 Brisbane my doc.doc |
| d:\2023_09_29 Brisbane | my file.doc | d:\2023_09_29 Brisbane\2023_09_29 Brisbane my file.doc |

I can rename all files in a folder, but can't work out how to do this for all subfolders.

This is what I am currently using to rename the files in the current folder:

`$(Get-ChildItem ./) | Rename-Item -NewName { $_.Directory.Name+' '+$_.Name}`

I have tried the following:

`Get-ChildItem -Path $Path -Recurse |  Rename-Item -NewName { $_.Directory.Name+' '+$_.Name}`

But it is giving me errors and seems to be renaming the filename multiple times.

I would really appreciate it if someone could provide me with advise on how to do this. Thanks!

Comment: You're missing `-File` to actually target only files, otherwise you're also renaming folders too

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to either **capture** the result of the `Get-ChildItem` cmdlet in a variable first and loop over that, or enclose the Get-ChildItem part in between brackets so it will gather the files to a finish before looping over the results.
Especially, since you do not use a `-Filter` here to find and rename only specific files, without capturing or bracketizing `Get-ChildItem` will happily enumerate newly renamed files again and again..

Try capturing first:

```
$allFiles = Get-ChildItem -Path $Path -File -Recurse
$allFiles | Rename-Item -NewName { '{0} {1}' -f $_.Directory.Name, $_.Name }
```

Or surround the enumeration of files witch brackets

```
(Get-ChildItem -Path $Path -File -Recurse) | Rename-Item -NewName { '{0} {1}' -f $_.Directory.Name, $_.Name }
```

Comment: This worked perfectly! Thankyou!

Answer (score 1):

Your approach using PowerShell is close, but you need to modify it slightly to avoid renaming files multiple times.

```
$Path = "D:\"

# Get all files recursively
Get-ChildItem -Path $Path -File -Recurse | ForEach-Object {
    $newName = Join-Path $_.Directory.FullName ($_.Directory.Name + " " + $_.Name)
    Rename-Item -Path $_.FullName -NewName $newName
}
```

**$Path** is set to the root directory, which is "D:" in your case. You can change this path to match your specific directory.

**Get-ChildItem -Path $Path -File -Recurse** retrieves all files recursively under the specified directory.

Inside the loop, we create a new name for the file by combining the directory's name and the original file name using **Join-Path**.

Finally, we use **Rename-Item** to rename the file with the new name.

This script will do the job. :D

Comment: Thanks, but that has not worked. It is running the code over each file multiple times, which is what it was doing with my original code.

The file names are now:

2023_09_28 Sydney 2023_09_28 Sydney 2023_09_28 Sydney 2023_09_28 Sydney 2023_09_28 Sydney 2023_09_28 Sydney 2023_09_28 Sydney 2023_09_28 Sydney 2023_09_28 Sydney 2023_09_28 Sydney 2023_09_28 Sydney 2023_09_28 Sydney my doc.doc